# How to change the names of the registers displayed with circuit_drawer (output='mpl')

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-circuit

I am trying to change the appearance of the circuit_drawer in output='mpl' mode. The registers of the Quantum Circuit are named like ($q0_0$, $q0_1$, $q1_0$, $q2_0$, $q2_1$,..) but I'd like to name them myself. I can't find a style function or option which is able to do that... any ideas?

To be clear what I would like to change:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When initializing the registers for the quantum circuit you need to set the parameter 'name'. For example:

```
f_in = QuantumRegister(n, name='f_in')
###add other registers here### 
qc = QuantumCircuit(f_in, ...)
qc.draw(ouput='mpl')
```

Gives the output:

[image]